# C# VS 2005: How to get a class's public member list during the runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection, typeof

I'm trying to get a class memeber variable list at run time. I know this probably using typeof and reflections. but can't find an example. Please someone shed light for me.

Here is pseudo code example:

```
Class Test01
{ 
 public string str01;
 public string str02;
 public int myint01;
}
```

I want something like this (pseudo code):

```
Test01 tt = new Test01();
foreach(variable v in tt.PublicVariableList)
{
   debug.print v.name;
   debug.print v.type;
}
```

Please help me figure out how to do this in C# VS2005

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're after public *fields* just use [`tt.GetType().GetFields()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfields.aspx)

If you need other members, use [GetProperties()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties.aspx), [GetMethods()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethods.aspx), [GetEvents()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getevents.aspx) etc for specific  ones, or [GetMembers()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmembers.aspx) to get them all.

Each method has an overload accepting a BindingFlags if you want to access non-public members, or restrict the search to static members (or just to instance members).

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (MemberInfo mi in tt.GetType().GetMembers()) ...
```